# How to change language of system clipboard text (Copy, Paste etc.,) to Chinese in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Mian',
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('zh','HK')
  ],
```

I want to change the Paste to 粘贴，Select All to 选择全部

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add `flutter_localizations` into `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

2. import `flutter_localizations` into `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
```

3. use `supportedLocales`

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      home: new HomePage(title: ''),
      localizationsDelegates: [                             
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('zh','CH'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```